# How to stop the application from closing while timer is running

Tags: c#

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        static bool isServerOn = false;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed += Update;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void Update(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1233);

                if (isServerOn) return;
                isServerOn = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Server is On");
            } catch(Exception)
            {
                if (!isServerOn) return;
                isServerOn = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Server Is Off");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i got this code for my client and the timer dont run because the application close after i run it can someone tell me how to make the timer run and the application dont close at the same time

Comment: add a `isServerOn = true; while (isServerOn) { }` statement behind enabling the timer. Don't have a clue though what you want to achieve with this program

Comment: i want it this application to detect if the server is on or off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this using Tasks.

Try this or something like it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(async () => {
            do
            {
                Update();
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            } while (isServerOn);
        });
        t.Wait();
    }
```

Comment: it worked but i had to edit on it i wanna check if server on even if its on so i did
while(true)
instead

Answer (score 5):

Well you can use a `Console.ReadKey()` or `Console.ReadLine()` method like below but you should actually make it a *WindowsService* application rather a normal console application

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += Update;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```